# GeoDjango hosting - any suggestions for a provider who actually supports this?

Tags: hosting, geodjango

I am attempting to build a GeoDjango site. I have tried three hosting providers so far and eventually run into a roadblock with each one.

The latest... A2Hosting seemed promising until I needed to run:
`sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin`

I was then informed that I need to move to an unmanaged VPS. This translates to I need to completely set up the entire system.
I attempted to do this, but feel I ended up creating more security vulnerabilities than getting it to work.
I know very little about the "sever" side and this is why I am trying to go to a "hosted" solution.

It seems the steps that need to be provided are:

- django support
- postgis support (including remote access - we want to be able to hit the database through QGIS as well)
- Support to install the geospatial dependencies needed to turn django into geodjango - this seems to be the show stoppper for most hosting providers.

Any suggestions for who to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Andrew, are you still stuck on this issue ?